# How to reinitialize a dropzone element

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dropzone.js, dropzone

I want to use dropzone to display thumbnails of images that I already have on the server. I am creating a CMS for a property website. The server has images associated with Sites of properties. When the page loads, the init function of my dropzone displays the relevant image for a given site as a thumbnail in the dropzone.

There is a drop down box on the page which lets the user select another site. When they do this I want the dropbox object to basically do what's in the init function again. Make a call to the server and display the thumbnails that are associated with this different site.

I haven't been able to get a solution yet (obviously). Typically I will get something like, "dropzone still attached" with stuff I have tried. I can't seem to see anything in the docs that is useful.

Any help would be appreciated :)

//my dropzone object

```
var myDropzone = $('#featured-development-dropzone').dropzone({
                    url: '@Url.Action("SaveFeaturedDevelopmentImage","Homepage")',
                    maxFiles: 1,
                    addRemoveLinks: true,
                    init: function () {
                        var myDropzone = this;
                        $("select").on('click', function () {
                            myDropzone.removeAllFiles(true);
                        });
                        var siteID = $('#siteDropdown').find(':selected').val();
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("GetFeaturedDevelopmentImage", "Homepage")',
                            data: { siteID: siteID },
                            type: 'GET',
                            success: function (data) {
                                console.log(data);
                                if (data.data != null) {
                                    var mockFile = {
                                        name: data.filename,
                                        size: data.fileSize
                                    };

                                    // Call the default addedfile event handler
                                    myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
                                    console.log(typeof (data));

                                    // And optionally show the thumbnail of the file:

                                    myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, "data:image/png;base64," + _arrayBufferToBase64(data.data));
                                    myDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        this.on("sending", function (file, xhr, formData) {
                            formData.append("SiteID", siteID);
                            formData.append("imageTypeID", 4);
                            console.log(formData);
                        });
                    }
                });


            var prevSiteID;
            $("select").on('click', function () {
                prevSiteID = this.value;
            }).change(function () {
                var newSIteID = this.value;
               // potentially put code here that will reinitialize the dropbox and display images associated with different site.                

                console.log(prevSiteID);
                console.log(newSIteID);
                changeFeaturedDevelopment(prevSiteID, newSIteID);
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive you need to recall that function again. Since when you are triying to attach a new image, the dropzone zone is already defined in the page load. Or you call the init again or try to reset it, so the dropzone can reattach another image.